# setTimeout doesn't work(JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

setTimeout does not work on the page. I cannot find the error. the console does not display any.

Here is my JQuery

```
var timer;
function sliderColorMain(){
  $('.news-main').mouseenter(function(){
     timer = setTimeout(function(){
      $(this).find('.sliding-color').slideDown(500);
    }, 200);
  }).mouseleave(function(){
      // clearTimeout(timer);
      $(this).find('.sliding-color').slideUp(250);
    });
}
```

Css File:

```
.sliding-color{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; /*100%*/
    background-color: #2573CF;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

This is my HTML file

```
<div class="news-main">
    <div class="sliding-color"></div>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="big-image">
                <img src="img/main.jpg" alt="big main image">
           </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

without setTimeout function this thing works, but the only problem is that if I hover the mouse and then leave it from the .news-main div class many times just one after another, the animation plays even if the mouse is not moving. So I added setTimeout, but it does not work. Actually, the animation with this function does not work too

Comment: `this` in the timed function is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are losing the reference to the correct `this` in the `setTimeout` callback. You can solve this in many ways, but arrow functions may be the easiest:

```
timer = setTimeout(() => {
    $(this).find('.sliding-color').slideDown(500);
}, 200);
```

Alternatively, you can use `bind`:

```
timer = setTimeout(function () {
    $(this).find('.sliding-color').slideDown(500);
}.bind(this), 200);
```

Or, save the jQuery expression before:

```
var $this = $(this);
timer = setTimeout(function () {
    $this.find('.sliding-color').slideDown(500);
}, 200);
```

Comment: actually, it was my fault. I reread now my question and both answers. The one which I ticked as correct one yesterday is what I really searched for, but I have asked my question incorrectly, so that your answer is fully correct to my question. Sorry for misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

Stoping the current animation and starting another might also work, set the id to your div .sliding-color to 'sliding-color' like

```
<div class="news-main">
    <div class="sliding-color" id='sliding-color'></div>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="big-image">
            <img src="img/main.jpg" alt="big main image">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

and here is the jquery code

```
function sliderColorMain(){
  $slidingColor = $('#sliding-color');
  $('.news-main').mouseenter(function(){
      $slidingColor.stop(true).slideDown(500);
  }).mouseleave(function(){
      $slidingColor.stop(true).slideUp(250);
    });
}
```